# Duplicate records which should be discrete after applying group by in aggregate windows function is missing

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT
    de.emp_no, de.dept_no, de.from_date, de.to_date
FROM
dept_emp de
    JOIN
(SELECT
    emp_no, MIN(from_date) AS from_date
FROM
    dept_emp
GROUP BY emp_no) de1 ON de.emp_no = de1.emp_no
WHERE
de.to_date > sysdate() and de.from_date = de1.from_date;
```

Well this code should return the result of the current employees from the salaries table and apply it to the department employees table.

Such a query will give us the correct list with the latest department and employee has worked in.

but as group by is used may be because of that duplicate(same employee who has worked in different department in different moment of time) employee number records is missing entiredly.

correct output ss1

[image]

correct output ss2

[image]

but

ss1

[image]

ss2

[image]

you can see in the img emp_no 10010 and 10018 are missing

I don't know what to do here . I want the missing records to be returned correctly and also want to know what mistake I did or what error I did cause and if there is any settings I need to make.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired output in plain text. Images are not available.